# how to apply existing global appearance to programmatically created UIElements dynamically?

Tags: ios

I have created a Navigation Bar programatically and it doesn't have the global tint color and text color set via appearance proxy globally.

All the storyboard created navigation bar has the attributes properly.

Comment: Apply the effect you'd like in your custom class.

Comment: but i have created the navigation bars at couple of places and i am looking for some way to make them look like other navigation bars in the application. so that i don't have to apply all the modifications every time i create them.

Comment: Exactly, that's why you subclass UINavigationBar and create your own class, ex: CustomNavigationBar. You can apply all the modifications in that class alone.

Comment: thanks for help. I just added a customization function to do this in appDelegate. that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a Method to dynamically apply new customizations to appearance proxies. that worked for me. Thanks.